# Incremental archiv with zpaq

Tags: backup, zpaq

I just start using zpaq. I want to compress Backups and do incremental backups to save disk space. To create a archive is no problem, but I did not found any solution to create a incremental archiv in a new file. The first I did was making a archive like this:

```
zpaq add archive.zpaq source
```

From time to time I want to create a new inremental archive frome the same source like this:

```
25.123.543   archive.zpaq
   123.321   001.zpaq
 1.293.724   002.zpaq
```

All I had tryed was not working. Is this possible to do this with zpaq? Have someone a hint for me? The reference an google was not helpfull for me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but maybe there are some people still searching for it.
You can use

```
zpaq add "archive????" source
```

this will first create a full backup and on each subsequent run an incremental backup.